# Javascript not loading another page into DIV

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having some troubles today. I am trying to get Javascript to load content into a `<div>`. Now, this is my JavaScript source code:

```
function loadXMLDoc(filename) {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            after_load_function(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", filename, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function after_load_function(responseText) {
    document.getElementById("right").innerHTML = responseText;
}

window.onload = function () {
    loadXMLDoc("welcome.html");
}
```

And my div:

```
<div id="right"></div>
```

Does anyone know the problem?

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong - check the network tab in the developer tools.

Comment: Is `welcome.html` in the same folder than the JavaScript file or HTML file containing this function?

Comment: Welcome.html is the folder it should load into the div. @n.1

Comment: Check your  console for errors

Comment: specifically you can check what your response is under network in the developer tools that should let you know whether your ajax call is working properly.  That might help ...just an idea

Comment: This code works. http://jsfiddle.net/kWQsh/

Comment: why not using jQuery. It will make your life easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there any reason you aren't using an abstraction like the JQuery `load` [method](http://api.jquery.com/load/)?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#right").load( "welcome.html" );
})
```

looks pretty good to me.

Comment: I found an tutorial, It worked yesterday but today I does not.

Comment: I assure you it will be *much* easier for you to use JQuery or another library abstraction than to mess with low-level details of the XHR and the DOM.

Comment: If I was to use it, how would the code look like? The main point is too load some text into a div when you load the website.

Comment: That's why I used JS to load the page into the div.

Comment: The code will look similar to what I have up in my answer. But for more details, check the link I provided as well.

Comment: Does the code you provided me, load the text when the website has loaded.

Comment: It loads the content of `welcome.html` into the div with id `right`. But the timing has to be in the JQuery `ready` method. I edited the answer to show how it might look. Here is the documentation of `ready` so you can tweak as needed: http://api.jquery.com/ready/. If you look at the references, you'll figure out what you need.

Comment: I really would love if you could help me get the code so it loads when your load the site.

Comment: Dude, as I've already said, the code in my answer does that. That's what `$(document).ready` does. You really need to make some effort. This isn't hacking the Pentagon.

Comment: Hi - thanks! I've been exploring information about JQuery. I was following some tutorials on a website (http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_load). I've been trying to find out how to change instead of using "Click" to load. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just had a similar issue, here is what I have and it seems to be working really well,

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> pageOne </title>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <input class='loadBtn' type='submit' value='Load a Different Page!:'>

    <div id="page"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
//click function:
$(".loadBtn").click(function(){

        //div to hide/replace
        $('#page')

            //fadeOut div content:
            .delay(200).fadeOut('slow')

            //load method:
            .load

            //url #divToReplace
            ('pageTwo.php #page')

            //fadeIn new div content:
            .hide().delay(300).fadeIn('slow');

        //prevent default browser behavior
        return false;
    });
```